# Mapping a multiindex dataframe to another using row ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

I have two dataframes of different shape

[image: Dataframe 1]

[image: DataFrame 2]

The **'ANTENNA1'** and **'ANTENNA2'** in the bigger dataframe correspond to the **ID** columns in the smaller dataframe. I want to create merge the smaller dataframe to the bigger one so that the bigger dataframe will have **'(POSITION, col1)'**, **'(POSITION, col2)'**, **'(POSITION, col3)'** according to **ANTENNA1 == ID**

Edit: I tried with pd.merge but it is changing the original dataframe column values

Original: [image]

df = pd.merge(df_main, df_sub, left_on='ANTENNA1', right_on ='id', how = 'left')

Result: [image]

I want to keep the original dataframe columns as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your first dataframe (with positions) is called `df1`, and the second is called `df2`, with your loaded data, you could just use [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html): ( -> pd.merge(...) )

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='id', right_on='ANTENNA1')
```

Than you might select the df on your needed columns(col1,col2,..) to get the desired result  df[["col1","col2",..]].

simple example:

```
# import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# creating dataframes as df1 and df2
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8],
                    'Name': ['Sam', 'John', 'Bridge',
                             'Edge', 'Joe', 'Hope']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9],
                    'Marks': [67, 92, 75, 83, 69, 56, 81]})

# merging df1 and df2 by ID
# i.e. the rows with common ID's get
# merged i.e. {1,2,5,8}
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="ID", right_on="id")
print(df)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that solution but it is changing the columns of the original dataframe. Check my edit:

Comment: @ArpanDas , the original dataframe(s)[df1,df2] should be the same. Resulting dataframe df you might have columns you want to exclude. You can select the columns as in my answer above. you could get full list of all columns with df.columns. From there choose the columns you need. Please check here for good explanation of "df-joins" and there equivalents to a database join(left,right,inner) https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/joins-in-pandas-master-the-different-types-of-joins-in-python/